# what workout should I do to have a high vertical jump?

Tags: training, volleyball

I'm a volleyball player but i lack the required vertical jump.

So can you please suggest the best workouts for a high vertical jump ?

Comment: Possibly this question might be more suitable for [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/). (At least that's what I was told [in their chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/324/2018/12/17).)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these basic tips:

**1: See what you are starting with**:  Start by standing next to a tall wall with a post-it note in your hand.  Jump as high as you possible can and leave the post-it note on the wall where you reach.  Measure how high you reach from the top of the post-it note to the ground.  Try to retest yourself every 2 weeks to gauge your progress.

**2: Learn how to build explosive power**:  Start building up your muscle memory with exercises that enhance your ability to propel yourself higher.  A good exercise to start with is by standing on a bench with one foot, and hopping down from the bench landing with both feet.  As you land, land in a squat and try to reverse your direction upwards  into a jump.  This exercise will help you learn to use the momentum you gained from jumping off the bench, to make your reverse jump up higher.

**3: Build your lower body:** Resistance training is a great way to increase your strength.  A few exercises to start with are leg presses, Bulgarian split squats, calf raises, and dead lifts.  As you train, try to use weights that allow you to do no more then 10 reps and no less then 5 reps and as you get stronger gradually increase the weight.  Do this training once a week and begin adding this slowly into your weekly workout to reduce your risk of injury.

**4: Jump Rope:**  As simple as jumping rope sounds, it can be very effective.  Jumping rope is great cardio and it also increases the size of your calf muscles.  Add jumping rope as fast as you can for 30 seconds into your daily exercise to see major results

Answer (score 2):

You should focus on:

1. Harmstrings
2. Quads
3. Calves
4. Glutes

I would do these exercices:

1. Squats
2. Jump squats
3. Calf raises
4. Just jumping!

Answer (score 0):

## Here are some exercises to help improve your vertical jump.

> Power and Strength Exercises for Jumping
>   Strength exercises include slow, controlled movements like squats, lunges, and weighted step-ups.  Power exercises require explosive, quick moves like those needed for plyometrics and power cleans. Plyometrics are explosive bounding, hopping and jumping drills that blend strength and speed. Finally, practicing maximum vertical jump will increase vertical jump.
>
> There are many ways to improve vertical jump, but some of the most effective exercises include plyometrics, along with exercises that build both strength and power.
>
> Plyometrics: The most common plyometric exercises include hops, jumps, and bounding movements. One popular plyometric exercise is jumping off a box and rebounding off the floor and onto another, higher box. Box jumps will also provide practice for jumping.
>
> Full Squats: This barbell exercise will build both strength and power. It's also one of the best total body exercises you can do.
>
> Weighted / Dynamic Step Ups: The step up is a great all-around exercise that you can do almost anywhere. Not only will it build strength in your quadriceps, you can also use it as part of a cardio workout. It has a low risk of injury.
>   Overhead Walking Lunges: This exercise builds power, strength, and speed in your legs as well as improving core strength during movement. All you need is a weight and room to walk.
>
> Single-leg Squats: The single leg squat is an exercise you can do anywhere, without equipment. It works your hips, hamstrings, quadriceps, gluteus maximus. and calves while strengthening your core and helping flexibility.
>
> Sprints:  These short bouts of intense exercise build muscle and performance, using more muscles at the same time as compared to weightlifting.
>   Agility drills: Agility drills to help improve coordination, speed, power, and specific sports skills. Several of them include jumping.
>
> Stair Running: Stair running is a high-intensity workout that helps build speed, power, and cardiovascular fitness. It targets the glutes, quads, and calves.

Also, it is proven that practicing your vertical jump strengthens it.

> Practice Your Maximum Jump
>   If you want to jump higher, jump higher. Include some time to practice your maximum jump, putting it all together. Work on your form, incorporating your lead up to the jump, arm motion, and safe landing technique.
>
> Keep in mind that jumping is a high impact activity. It isn't suitable for everyone and you may discover it is taking a toll on your knees, hips, ankles, and feet. Be sure to give your body a rest between hard workouts so your muscles have time to repair and build before you challenge them again.